# Building an array in PHP with Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, loops, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to build an array in Codeigniter 3, but I cant seem to structure it properly.

I have 2 tables that I basically need to combine; questions and their associated answers.

SO, basically I need a multidimensional array, each inner array is to contain the question data along with its associated answer data.

This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
$question_array = array();

foreach($course_object->result() as $question){

    $question_array[] = array (
      'question_id' => $question->question_id,
      'question'    => $question->question,
    );

    $answer_data = $this->get_answer_data($question->question_id);

    foreach($answer_data as $answer){
        $question_array[]['answer'] = $answer->answer;
        $question_array[]['result'] = $answer->result;
    }
}

return $question_array;
```

But that outputs each question as an array on its own, as well as each answer, i need to combine them somehow. This is what I'm getting:

```
array(2) {
  ["question_id"]=>
  string(3) "548"
  ["question"]=>
  string(29) "Who enforces fire safety law?"
}

array(1) {
  ["answer"]=>
  string(11) "The Manager"
}

array(1) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}



array(1) {
  ["answer"]=>
  string(18) "The Fire Authority"
}


array(1) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

and this is what i need:

```
array(2) {
  ["question_id"]=>
  string(3) "548"
  ["question"]=>
  string(29) "Who enforces fire safety law?"
  ["answer"]=>
  string(11) "The Manager"
  ["result"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["answer"]=>
  string(18) "The Fire Authority"
  ["result"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

I've tried things like array_push but I cant seem to get it to work?

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_export($course_object->result());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to create a new array with what you need, and append it to the `$question_array`, like this. You'll need a new subarray for the answers, because you can't have duplicate keys in an array.

```
foreach($course_object->result() as $question){

    $q_array = array (
        'question_id' => $question->question_id,
        'question'    => $question->question,
        'answers'     => array()
    );

    $answer_data = $this->get_answer_data($question->question_id);

    foreach($answer_data as $answer){
        $q_array['answers'][] = array(
            'answer' => $answer->answer,
            'result' =>$answer->result
        );
    }
    $question_array[] = $q_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
$question_array = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($course_object->result() as $question){

    $question_array[$i] = array (
      'question_id' => $question->question_id,
      'question'    => $question->question,
    );

    $answer_data = $this->get_answer_data($question->question_id);

    foreach($answer_data as $answer){
        $question_array[$i]['answer'][] = $answer->answer;
        $question_array[$i]['result'][] = $answer->result;
    }

    $i++;
}

return $question_array;
```